# Calculate stock price range using standard deviation

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-analysis, technical-analysis, risk-management

New to stock investing hence reading up a few tutorial to better understand stocks/stock market. Came across a chapter that says, "Understanding risk with the stock market" and it says that traders and analysts use a number of metrics to assess the volatility and relative risk of potential investments (sharpe ratio, sortino ratio, beta, alpha, rsquared), but the most common metric is standard deviation.

I somewhat get what standard deviation is,

- Standard deviation helps determine market volatility or the spread of asset prices from their average price.
- When prices move wildly, standard deviation is high, meaning an investment will be risky.
- Low standard deviation means prices are calm, so investments come with low risk.

There is an example too which says, in a stock with a mean price of $45 and a standard deviation of $5, it can be assumed with 95% certainty **the next closing price remains between $35 and $55**. However, price plummets or spikes outside of this range 5% of the time. A stock with high volatility generally has a high standard deviation, while the deviation of a stable blue-chip stock is usually fairly low.

What I did not understand is how did the above example calculate the range of the stock price to be in between $35 to $55?

How do you calculate the fluctuation price range if you know the stock price and the standard deviation value?

Answer (score 1):

What a lot of financial analysis relies on is the idea that stock returns follow a *Normal Distribution*. This distribution relies on two parameters, the mean and standard deviation. Based on the properties of the normal distribution, it is said that any given value will fall between +-2 standard deviations from the mean 95% of the time. From your example, a stock with a mean price of $45 and a standard deviation of $5 will trade from $35 ($45 - 2($5)| -2 standard deviations) to $55 ($45+2($5) | +2 standard deviations) 95% of the time.

[image: Example Normal Distribution]